# How to create a new Live ID and check exists id from Web?

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest

So, i want to create the tool to register a new Live ID & check exists Id vailable [Winform- C# - HttpWebRequest]
I used fiddler to catch GET/POST request but i didn't see parameters post to server (username=xxx&password=xxx&xxx).
Register link: [Live.com](https://signup.live.com/signup.aspx?lic=1)
how can i do ?

Winform : 
- Textbox : Username, Password, Email Address
- Show captcha form signup.live.com for user fill
- Button : Register.
When i click button, it will auto-register(get parameters user fill) on signup.live.com.

=================
edit : sniff by fiddler  :

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Major Version: 3
Minor Version: 1
Random: 52 1A 03 D2 81 48 F0 3B FD CB 50 8C C8 EE 1B 57 48 8E A9 0E 52 AB 95 0B 7E 82 EA BE 61 AA CF C6
SessionID: A2 44 00 00 96 50 7B 3E 2C 90 02 4B 58 3E 02 D7 0A 3C D3 5A C9 C3 7C 92 49 BF 54 4D 3B 55 96 9C
Ciphers: 
    [00FF]  TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
    [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0088]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [0087]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [0039]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [C00F]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C005]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0084]  TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [C007]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C011]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0045]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0044]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0033]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [C00C]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [C00E]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C002]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [C004]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0096]  TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
    [0041]  TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [C008]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    [C012]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    [0016]  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [C00D]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    [C003]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    [FEFF]  SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION

Extensions: 
    server_name signup.live.com
    elliptic_curves 00 06 00 17 00 18 00 19
    ec_point_formats    01 00
    SessionTicket TLS   empty
    NextProtocolNegotiation empty
```

Comment: Could you add some more details about what it is exactly that you are trying to do? I sense that you want to authenticate users with their LiveID. You could use [OAuth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/live/hh243647.aspx) for that.

Comment: I found a video tutorial that might help you: http://mrbool.com/windows-live-id-service-programming-lesson-4-how-to-create-new-live-id-and-changing-password-using-live-id-api/16322

Comment: i has seen this video, but Microsoft not supports Service at the moment. thanks

Comment: Did you turn on HTTPS view on Fiddler as without that you wont see it , it does exist in the new version if you have it.

Comment: @confusedMind i had turn on but i not see it

Comment: @user1465351 Btw why are you not using webbrowser for this?